# JSON field's names in the Web Service response

Tags: c#, wcf, f#

I use F#, but I believe the question is not F# specific.
I have the interface for Web Service:

```
[<ServiceContract>]
type IRestService =
    [<OperationContract>]    
    [<WebGet(UriTemplate  = "Maintenance", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)>]
    abstract GetMaintenancesRest: a:unit -> Maintenance[]
```

When I am trying to use this service I can get JSON, but all field's names in the JSON have the symbol '@':

> [{"Address@":"one","Assetid@":"","Assignmentdate@":"/Date(1434147917730-0700)/","Comment@":"" ...

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to delete my question?

Answer (score 0):

It's F#.  I ran into this a *long* time ago, so I might be forgetting.  As I recall you may not use records to return from the service, or you get this error.  You need class types with properties.  I don't think mutable records work either.  I also don't think public fields work; it's got to be public read/write properties.